# Moving the monero blockchain data to another directory on windows 10

Tags: blockchain, windows

Just installed monero and syncing with default settings. How would I move the monero blockchain data to another directory like an SD card. And how do I tell monero the new location of these files?

Comment: I downloaded half of the blockchain already. How can I move it to my new location? Where is the default download location?

Comment: `C:\ProgramData\bitmonero\``.  Just drag or cut and paste that `bitmonero` folder where you want it to be, and then point the daemon at it with the `--data-dir "\new\location"` flag.